# Is it possible to mimic clicking a tray icon with a console command?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

In the Bitcoin Core client, when I have 'Minimize to the tray instead of the taskbar' enabled, the application's icon occasionally doesn't show up in tray and can't open the application window again unless I close bitcoin-qt through the system monitor and restart it.

It probably isn't a bug in the Bitcoin client, because it has happened with other programs as well. So, is it possible to open the window of an already running application by a console command?

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, xfce desktop environment.

Comment: If you install `wmctrl`, `man wmctrl` will tell you how to list current windows and how to bring a specific window back into focus.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica I'm assuming it lists windows that are open or minimized, not applications that are running with closed windows. When I go the process in my 'System Monitor' I do not have the option to 'Show Application Window' if the window has been closed. It only works when a window is minimized or hidden behind another window.

Comment: Do you confirm that the window of the minimized app really is not anymore listed in the output of `wmctrl -l`? What is your system monitor? I do not see such options in neither "System Monitor" (Gnome Shell) or Task Manager (xfce).

Comment: @vanadium I can confirm that, yes. My system monitor is: KSysGuard (KDE System Monitor).

Comment: Okay, so are you using Xubuntu, Kubuntu or something in between?

Comment: As for what `wmctrl` shows or not, why not just try?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Xubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I did try it; it doesn't show up as I suspected it wouldn't. Fortunately the Bitcoin Core tray icon is visible in the tray for now, and I can't seem reproduce the bug. However, my question still remains valid because I want to know if it is possible.

Comment: Maybe try a gtk version of your bitcoin app if such exists? I don't know anything about bitcoin but qt apps may do odd things in a non-qt environment?